# How to report posts that seemingly try to hijack browsers?

Tags: discussion, spam, security

Today, I stumbled over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030292/editing-a-facebook-friend-auto-tag-script). It already had some downvotes, but to me it made (and still makes) the impression that the Javascript code's purpose was to hijack anyone who executes it.

The obfuscated code made the impression to me that the OP was hiding something and as the question also wasn't really clearly asking something, I felt the need to report it to moderators.

Therefore I flagged it as spam, but my flag was declined. While I understand that questions with hundred words *spammy spam spam* are more clearly spam than this, I think that under the assumption that the code in the post was trying to hijack with obfuscated code, the *spam* flag seemed the most appropriate to me.

My question therefore is: What is the correct way to report a post that might have negative side-effects to users who in some way (try to) execute the code in it?

Comment: If you are positive as to the intent of the post then you can also edit the malicious code or edit a warning into the post.

Comment: @slugster I think that's a really good idea, I haven't thought of that. Do you think this is also a recommended procedure for <2k users who need edit approval? After all, it might matter to remove/warn of the post as fast as possible. However, you could simply add a comment, even if not anyone would read that.

Comment: Yep, submit an edit request while flagging. Edit suggestions usually get actioned pretty quickly, this is another way to call attention to the post in case the mod flag doesn't get processed immediately.

Comment: Very suspicious, I partially deobfuscated the code and inside there is something about "Assam Indian Cyber Force".

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Thanks for taking the time to really do it, on my part this was only speculation. This is really suspicious ;-) The question has now been removed from a moderator.

Answer (score 4):

Flag as **other (needs ♦ moderator attention)** would seem more appropriate to me. You can add a comment that states your findings.

I've flagged it as such.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion! Would you say that the *spam* flag should only be used for questions not containing any valuable content at all and not for any other purposes?

Comment: Spam is people advertising, posting unrelated propaganda, link farming all that nonsense. Luckily you rarely see any of it so you might wonder why we have the flag :) Generally speaking I would say that if the vote does not stand for itself you should pick the option that allows you to enter a comment. SO is designed so that it always offers a way out in case you stumble on an exception.